# Collection View inside Table View Cell not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement a collection view inside a table view cell.

My table view cell is a xib, and I've dragged a collection view into it.

Then, I created a class and xib for the collection view cell:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var media: Image?

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func initialize(media: PostImage) {
        self.media = media

        if let url = media.url {
            imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: url))
        }
    }

}
```

And I've given the xib the class "MyCollectionViewCell" and also given it the identifier "MyCollectionViewCell".

Then, in my table view cell class, I have done the following:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var post: Post!

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mediaCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        mediaCollectionView.delegate = self
        mediaCollectionView.dataSource = self

        let mediaCollectionViewCell = UINib(nibName: "MyCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        mediaCollectionView.register(mediaCollectionViewCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MyCollectionViewCell.")
        }

        let media = post.images[indexPath.row]

        cell.initialize(media: media)

        return cell
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func initialize(post: Post) {
        self.post = post

        title.text = post.title

        self.mediaCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The problem is, the collection view never shows when I run this. The title  label text shows fine, but the collection view does not show, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

`cellForItemAt` doesn't even seem to get called, because when I add `print("hello")` at the top of the function, it never shows up in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the height of the collection view is very small that it isn't shown.
Try to set the height for the table view cell:

```
func tableView(_: UITableView, heightForRowAt _: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return 100
}
```

where the 100 should be bigger than the collection view

Comment: The table view and table view cell are showing. It's the collection view and cell that aren't.

Comment: @user6724161 did you find a solution